# How do I make an inline list respect margins without hyphenation?

Tags: lists, hyphenation, enumitem, inline

I'm using the `enumitem` package to create inline lists in my resume. I currently have a snippet of code that looks like

```
\begin{description}
    \item[Frameworks/Libraries:]
    \begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin={{,}},label=]
        \item Flask
        \item Node.js
        \item Google Chrome Extensions
        \item jQuery
        \item Swing/AWT
        \item JUnit
        \item iOS
        \item Android
        \item ScalaTest
        \item pygame
    \end{enumerate*}
\end{description}
```

However, this code will break the margin within JUnit, hyphenating it as "J-Unit." I don't want any words in my resume to be hyphenated, so I put `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` at the top, but then that makes my list run into the margin instead of continuing on the next line. Adding `\raggedright` makes the lines far too uneven to be presentable. How can I both ensure that my inline list respects the margins and doesn't hypenate? I would like the last list items that don't fit to be added to the next line.

Comment: Please post a complete Minimum Working Example which compiles and demonstrates the problem you are having. This will greatly increase your chances of receiving useful answers by helping people to help you.

Comment: I think the answer is, however, likely to be that you really ought not want to do this as it is not going to look at all good typographically. Essentially, you want to allow interword spaces to become indefinitely large. That's possible but will look terrible because the 'gaps' in lines will look wrong. This might not be quite such a concern with a CV as with some other types of document but if you are using things like inline lists, the problem is surely going to be noticeable. One thing you could do is reorder your list to get acceptable output (if the order is not important).

Comment: You can add `\sloppy` after `\begin{description}`.

Comment: It is true `\raggedright` is too ragged, but the package `ragged2e` allows less ragged versions of ragged-right typesetting.

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I'm asking whether the inner list is really necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in inline lists as `enumerate*` a parameter called `afterlabel` is set to be an unbreakable space (`~`). Since your `label` is empty this unbreakable space connects two consecutive items, so that they cannot be broken.

The solution is to define also `afterlabel` to be empty and add a space to `itemjoin`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
    \item[Frameworks/Libraries:]
    \begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin={{, }},afterlabel={},label={}]
        \item Flask
        \item Node.js
        \item Google Chrome Extensions
        \item jQuery
        \item Swing/AWT
        \item JUnit
        \item iOS
        \item Android
        \item ScalaTest
        \item pygame
    \end{enumerate*}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

However, I wonder why you couldn't just use this simpler code, without the need for an inline `enumerate`:

```
\begin{description}
    \item[Frameworks/Libraries:] Flask, Node.js, Google Chrome Extensions,
          jQuery, Swing/AWT, JUnit, iOS, Android, ScalaTest, pygame
\end{description}
```